# How to merge files with line-skipping

Tags: perl, bash, awk

Have two files:

file `f1` has the next structure (after the # are comments which are not in the file)

```
SomeText1                #Section name - one word [a-zA-Z]
acd:some text            #code:text - the code contains only [a-z]
opo:some another text    #variable number of code:text pairs
wed:text too             #in the SomeText1 section are 3 pairs
SomeText2
xxx:textttt              #here only 1 code:text pair
SomeText3
zzz:texxxxxxx            #here only 1 code:text pair too
```

and file `f2` what contains in the same order as the above file the next lines:

```
1000:acd:opo:wed:123.44:4545.23:1233.23    #3 codes - like in the above segment 1
304:xxx:10:11:12.12                        #1 code - these lines contains only 
4654:zzz:0                                 #codes and numbers
```

the desired output is

```
SomeText1:1000:acd:opo:wed:123.44:4545.23:1233.23
acd:some text:
opo:some another text:
wed:text too:
SomeText2:304:xxx:10:11:12
xxx:textttt:
SomeText3:4654:zzz:0
zzz:texxxxxxx:
```

So need to add the lines from the `f2` to "section name" line. The codes in every line in the `f2` file are the same as the codes in the code:text pairs in the `f1`

Haven't no idea how to start, because

- can't use the `paste` command because i don't have the same line-count in the both files, and
- can't use `join`, because here aren't common keys in both files.

So, would be really happy, when someone tell me SOME ALGORITHM, how to start - and I will program it myself.

Comment: What? This is what writing code is about. I highly suggest you try this yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm offering you different approach - I provide a code, and you should figure out how it works ;) :)

```
paste -d':' f1 <(perl -pe '$\="\n"x($c=()=/[a-z]+/g)' <f2)
```

produces exactly what you want from your inputs.

EDIT - Explanation:

- The soultion comes from your comment *the lines contains only codes and numbers*. Therefore it is possible easily get the codes from the line.
- therefore enough enter as many empty lines after each line - how many codes you have
- the `/[a-z]+/g` matched every `code` and return them
- the `$c =()=` is the "Rolex operator" - what allows count the list of matches
- the count of matched codes gives the number how much empty lines are needed
- the `$\ = "\n" x NUMBER` - mean repeat NUMBER times the string before `x, e.g. when have 3 codes, will repeat 3 times the "\n" (newline) character.
- the newlines are added to the variabe `$\` - output record sep.
- and because the `-p` switch process the file by lines and print every line in the form "print $_$\;" - so after every line will print the output record separator - what contains a number of newlines.
- therefore we get empty lines

I hope than my english was enough ok for the explanation.

Comment: Running the perl produces the file with empty lines a and have the same line count as `f1` so it is possible to paste. Perlvar said the $\ is the output line separator and the `/[a-z]+/g` matches the `codes`. The remaining is not very clear .. :( But it is works, so accept and thank you. :)

Comment: @cajwine that's awesome. you're just going to "ship-it", even though you clearly have no idea how this works.

Comment: This is really cute and perly.

Answer (score 1):

Or wholly in Perl:

```
my $skip;
while (<$f1>) {
   chomp;
   my $suffix;
   if ($skip--) {
      $suffix = "\n";
   } else {
      $suffix = <$f2>;
      $skip = () = $suffix =~ /[a-z]+/g;
   }

   print "$_:$suffix";
}
```